# f {$$state: {…}} in request instead of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, post

I'm trying to create request with data in it but it gives only f {$$state: {…}} in console

```
$scope.createTask = function () {

    var req = $http.post('api/insert', {
        title: $scope.newTitle,
        description: $scope.newDescription,
        date: $scope.newDate
    })
    .then(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }, function (err){
        console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(req);
}
```

And this is server.js part:

`app.post('/api/insert', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.title);
});`

In Network section of browser the data is appeared, but on server side it's `undefined`. And btw request is endless pending

Comment: `req` is a *promise*. It has no data yet/itself - and trying to log it is "usually not correct". Use the Browser Developer Tools (instead of `console.log`) to monitor the network/XHR traffic: what does *the network tab* show?

Comment: @user2864740 ok but on the server side it's `undefined`

Comment: So what does the *network traffic* show? That will either 1) solve the issue or 2) allow the question/issue to be reasonably focused.

Comment: @user2864740 insert request endless pending

Comment: In NodeJS/Express, don't you need to do something explicitly in the handler to "send a response"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was with this part

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

I forgot to add it and `res.body.title`, not `res.title`